# Change color of bar on hover with FLOT charts

Tags: javascript, flot

Is it possible to change the color of a bar on hover with Flot horizontal bar charts

Comment: Please read the [documentation](https://github.com/flot/flot/blob/master/API.md): `highlightColor: color or number`

Comment: It dosent work yet, The opacity given for the bar colors on mouse hover still overrides the highlightColor i dont know why but i will try and figure it out. This is very helpful. Thank you

Answer (score 5):

This worked for me by setting the 'highlightColor' field:

```
$.plot("#placeholder", [data], {
    series: {
        bars: {
            show: true,
            align: 'center',
            barWidth: .6,
            horizontal: true
        },
        highlightColor: 'rgb(190,232,216)'
    },
    grid: {
        hoverable: true
    }
});
```

See this [fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ringstaff/LVSG3/26/) for working example.