# Flot change bar opacity on hover

Tags: jquery, flot

The default flot bar chart changes from opacity:.5 to an opacity:1 on hover.  I would like to invert this but I can not seem to find anyone that has done this.  This it the code that I am currently using.

```
$.extend(true, opts.flot, {
    series: {
        points: { show: false },
        bars: {
            align      : 'center',
            order      : (opts.stacked) ? null : true,
            show       : true,
            border     : false,
            fill       : 1,
            fillColor  : null,
            horizontal : opts.horizontal,
            barWidth   : (opts.stacked) ? 0.6 : 0.6 / opts.data.length,
            lineWidth  : 0
        },
        lines: { show: false },
        pie: { show: false }
    }
});
```

Comment: So do you have any code responsible for the hovering function? in this code, you are only defining the parameters of the object.

Comment: I dont have an added hover function.  I am currently using the default settings.  I am looking to override that default.

Comment: I do not see any code related to the changing of opacity in this code.

Comment: The default flot system changes the opacity from .5 to 1.  By setting fill to 1 it overrides the .5 and I have solid bars.  What I am looking for is the setting for me to override their system to change the default 1 to .5 on hover.

Comment: changing the code to something like this may give you a clue: 
`fillColor: {
                    colors: [{
                        opacity: 1
                    }, {
                        opacity: 0.5
                    }]
                }`
and also, do you have any JSFiddle code so I can take a look at?

Comment: No.  What you just did was change the color to a gradient

Comment: Found [a post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13266803/change-color-of-bar-on-hover-with-flot-charts) that may help you. I can post the answer for you if this post help you

Comment: with this you can not change the opacity, but you can change the fill color for hover.

Answer (score 0):

Use something like this in your options to give you `opacity 1` without hover and `opacity 0.5` on hover (here with red as base color):

```
color: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)',
highlightColor: 'rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5)',
bars: {
    show: true,
    fillColor: 'rgba(255, 0, 0, 1.0)'            
}
```

See this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/aqar3tgr/) for a full example.